# why algebra , analysis and topology are considered as very important topics in graduate programmes coursework?

Tags: soft-question, education

why algebra , analysis and topology  are considered as very important topics in graduate programmes coursework ?

Note : Im still pursuing my master and im going to do phd in future

I see many U.S and other country university this three subject algebra , analysis and topology are always included and make as a compuslory subject  in course work

I don't understant why this  three topics are make compulsory ?

why  not only  analysis ?  or why not only Algebra ? why not only topology?

Comment: You usually need some background in all three of these areas no matter what area of pure mathematics you'll eventually specialize in. Also, these three areas (especially algebra and analysis) tend to be good "measuring rods" for determining a student's potential, so (U.S. perspective follows) one's performance in graduate level algebra and analysis courses, as well as one's performance on the Ph.D. qualifying exams in algebra and analysis, tend to be good predictors of future successful completion of a Ph.D. in pure mathematics.

Comment: oks thanks u sir @DaveL.Renfro

Comment: Not only that, but a Ph.D. in mathematics indicates that one has achieved mastery of a breadth of *basic* graduate level mathematics along with the intensive research experience in one (typically more narrow) area. In addition, one needs a  broader background to read (and do) research than many students expect.

Comment: You can barely do any of these without a solid background in the remaining two anyway.